# dataset.xsd with **NO** app.config

Tags: c#, xsd, app-config

I've got an app with a dataset.xsd; I'm being asked to eliminate the app.config (one of those situations where we want to minimize visible change to the environment). I don't know if that's possible or not, but if there is a way I need to find it.

What we'd like to do is have the dataset just build the connection string in our code, and totally eliminate the app.config.

This (naturally) also needs to survive rebuilding, so I doubt I can make the change in the dataset.Designer.cs or Settings.Designer.cs.

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just uncheck the box to store the connection string in the app.config when you create the tableadapter?

Comment: We've got dozens of tables and table adapters; is there a way to change this after the fact?

Answer (score 6):

In your xsd you should have a xml node that should look like

```
<Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Settings" AppSettingsPropertyName="DevDataConnectionString" ConnectionStringObject="" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="DevDataConnectionString (Settings)" ParameterPrefix="@" PropertyReference="ApplicationSettings.SandboxConsole.Properties.Settings.GlobalReference.Default.DevDataConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What you need to do is delete the `AppSettingsObjectName`, `AppSettingsPropertyName` and `PropertyReference` attributes, copy your connection string inside `ConnectionStringObject`, then change `IsAppSettingsProperty` to `false`.

What you should end up with is a line that looks like

```
<Connection ConnectionStringObject="Data Source=SRCHAMBERLAIN;Initial Catalog=DevData;Integrated Security=True" IsAppSettingsProperty="false" Modifier="Assembly" Name="DevDataConnectionString (Settings)" ParameterPrefix="@" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Once you make the change right click the `YourDataSet.xsd` file in the solution explorer and choose "Run Custom Tool" from the rightclick menu to re-generate the `YourDataSet.Designer.cs` file.

Once you do that you can delete the `DevDataConnectionString` object from your project settings.

---

**Optional:** Do a find and replace of the content of the `Name` attribute so you can rename `DevDataConnectionString (Settings)` to something without the "(Settings)" tacked on the end. You need to update both the `Name` attribute on the `Connection` node and all `ConnectionRef` attributes on `DbSource` nodes elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.  Sounds like it should be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: What an incredible solution to a horrendous bug.  How did you know to do this?  Deleting `AppSettingsObjectName` and `AppSettingsPropertyName` and letting them regenerate seemed obvious to me as well, but not the other stuff.

Comment: @user1477388 I created two xsd files one with the string in the settings file and one without using the UI, i then compared the two files